# Highcharts PDF download with more categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have some 50 charts comprised of basic column and basic bar charts. User can download required charts as PDF with some conditions. At time the time of downloading these charts as PDF we have a common method call which will be executed for the report types. We consider Categories on each type of charts to generate a customized PDF size by customizing options Sourcewidth and SourceHight. One potential problem that i face when there were huge number of categories on axis. Assume, i have a basic bar graph with more categories on axis and which i want see all of them on the downloaded chart(assume in as 1000 categories). I can increase SouceHight value and get the required chart this case. But, i have basic column charts which also have categories on opponent axis to basic bar chart. Let assume, i have datetimehour values on axis for a period of two years and i have some bars located at particular hour on these two years span and, i have some 20000 categories on the axis(because of datetimehour) to be on the downloaded chart but at least i want to see those bars on the downlaoded chart instead of all the datehours on the axis and more in this case i increase soursewidth to be accommodate more values in the downloaded pdf. But, At the application level comprises of all this charts, i don't know a proper solution to download a good looking pdf.

I am sorry that i can't produce a exact fiddle but i have a fiddle with basic bar chart with more categories on that here http://jsfiddle.net/7racxxu0/14/

And assume the 20000 categories on opponent axis in basic column chart for the second issue.

Any help would be more appreciated.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },

    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['ghdg', 'kndfkjl', 'ytryr', 'Bananas', 'pop', 'errte', 'oi', 'Oranges1', 'Bananas1', 'Carrots1', 'Appls2', 'Pears2', 'wosflsj', 'ertet', 'yuyu', 'Ales', 'ioi', 'opl', 'bcvcx', 'Carots', 'Apes1', 'opop', 'Oranges1', 'yuiiui', 'Carrots1', 'errt', 'oioi', 'ioo', 'Bananas2', 'bfhjf', 'Apples', 'xxcc', '6546', 'Bananas', '646', 'tyuyf', 'rtr', 'rty', 'opuuui', 'fghf', 'tyuy', 'err', 'rewporij', 'xcvgff', 'ee', 'bvnvb', 'bnn', 'kjhfkdg', 'tytryt', '2121', 'Apples1', 'xvx', 'iyyuy', 'bnbn', 'yuyu', 'fgs', 'Pears2', 'orwuepr', 'ppwppw', 'Crots2', 'Apes', '545', 'nmvh', '855963', '96489', 'iuio', '8998', 'ghtrf', 'nff', 'Cats1', 'Apes2', '2333', 'itrosfgn', 'Banas2', 'zasar', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', , 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', , 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        min: 100
    }],
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },
    series: [{
        data: [3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6, 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6, 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6, 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }],
     exporting: {
            sourceWidth: 1200,
            sourceHeight: 3200, 

            chartOptions: {
                xAxis: [{
                    categories: ['ghdg', 'kndfkjl', 'ytryr', 'Bananas', 'pop', 'errte', 'oi', 'Oranges1', 'Bananas1', 'Carrots1', 'Appls2', 'Pears2', 'wosflsj', 'ertet', 'yuyu', 'Ales', 'ioi', 'opl', 'bcvcx', 'Carots', 'Apes1', 'opop', 'Oranges1', 'yuiiui', 'Carrots1', 'errt', 'oioi', 'ioo', 'Bananas2', 'bfhjf', 'Apples', 'xxcc', '6546', 'Bananas', '646', 'tyuyf', 'rtr', 'rty', 'opuuui', 'fghf', 'tyuy', 'err', 'rewporij', 'xcvgff', 'ee', 'bvnvb', 'bnn', 'kjhfkdg', 'tytryt', '2121', 'Apples1', 'xvx', 'iyyuy', 'bnbn', 'yuyu', 'fgs', 'Pears2', 'orwuepr', 'ppwppw', 'Crots2', 'Apes', '545', 'nmvh', '855963', '96489', 'iuio', '8998', 'ghtrf', 'nff', 'Cats1', 'Apes2', '2333', 'itrosfgn', 'Banas2', 'zasar', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', , 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', , 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                    min: 0,
                    max: 113
                }]
            }
        }
});
```

});

Comment: If you want just to export a part of your chart, you can't. The function only works for the whole chart. And because the exporting function works with the highcharts server we can't change it to fulfill our needs. The only solution I can think of is to change the data series and let the chart only show the values you want to export.

Comment: I am not using Highchart's export and i am not even trying to export a part of chart. I am trying to export whole chart.

Comment: How are you not using `Highchart`s export? You are using `Sourcewidth` and `SourceHeight` in `exporting`

Comment: OH! sorry,I am using export as like in the fiddle.

Comment: I tested the fiddle, the whole chart is exporting fine both in `pdf` and `jpg` format. I don't understand your question. Can you please simplify or make an example based on your fiddle?